# Where I can find libopenexr.so in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04, openexr

I want to build some code example which depends on *libopenexr* library.

I found these two packages:

```
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~/OpenGLSB5E_build$ apt-cache search openexr
...
libopenexr-dev - development files for the OpenEXR image library
libopenexr6 - runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
...
```

I tried to install them, however they are already installed:

```
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~/OpenGLSB5E_build$ sudo apt-get install libopenexr6 libopenexr-dev
...
libopenexr-dev is already the newest version.
libopenexr6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I see include files in */usr/include*, however I cannot find the corresponding library. So I cannot link project.
I made several tries like:

```
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~/OpenGLSB5E_build$ ldconfig -p |grep exr
wiesniak@wiesniak-Precision-M4800:~/OpenGLSB5E_build$
```

but it looks like it is not available in the system.

Any idea where it can be ?
What should I do more ?
How can I find it ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the answer.

I assume that library name will be somthing like: libopenexr*.so, but I was wrong.

The correct name of library provided by libopenexr package is libIlmImf

```
** IlmImf - a library that reads and writes OpenEXR images.**
```

Best Regards

Greg

P.S. I will never understand why people gave such names, that is even impossible to pronounce, not even mention not related to package name at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try [dlocate](https://helpmanual.io/help/dlocate/):

```
 dlocate openexr
```

the result is:

```
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopenexr.so
libopenexr24:amd64: /.
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_3.so.24.0.0
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImfUtil-2_3.so.24.0.0
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/doc
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopenexr24
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopenexr24/changelog.Debian.gz
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopenexr24/copyright
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/lintian
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/lintian/overrides
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libopenexr24
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_3.so.24
libopenexr24:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImfUtil-2_3.so.24
...
```

OpenEXR is based on the tools for Low-level operations on files  with:

- image format (imf)
- created by Industrial Light & Magic (ilm)

so library ( lib) is named libIlmImf.

The name is changing, in OpenEXR 3.x, the library will be [libOpenEXR](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr/issues/879).